# dynamically changing GridView template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a gridview template field that's a dropdownlist.

On Edit for certain rows I was to display less items than other rows.

How can this be done?

Comment: create multiple templates, and assign each template to the row in code behind.

Comment: @clarity - what determines how much data to show?  Querystring, session, row value?

Comment: Show us the code you use to populate the dropdownlist.

Comment: the list of items is actually hardcoded. it's like "a", "b", "c", "d" and for rows that don't have "a" selected I don't want to show it. In other words, if "a" is selected then the DDL should have "a", "b", "c", "d" and if it's not then it should just have "b", "c", "d"

Answer (score 1):

Do this work on 'GridView1_RowEditing' Event.
on row edit capture the values in textbox (which you are changing).
depending on the value create a list of items you want to show.

Bind dropdownlist in  current row

```
gr.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

GridViewRow editingRow = grv.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

DropDownList ddlPbx = (editingRow.FindControl("ddlPBX") as DropDownList);
if (ddlPbx != null)
{
    ddlPbx.DataSource = _pbxTypes;
    ddlPbx.DataBind();
}
```